# Deploying 10 identical iPads to 10 users with preloaded content that won't be wiped when connected to iTunes

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pre-install apps on an iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/is-it-possible-to-pre-install-apps-on-an-ipad)

I am looking into deploying 10 iPads with identical content to 10 different people.

Each iPad needs to be set up for an individual end user before hand, with content on it and then be able to sync to their own iTunes if/when they connect it to their PC or Mac.  Ideally I'd like to prevent the iPads from being wiped/reset when they connect to their iTunes - however I know this may be tricky.

Assuming each iPad will need it's own iTunes account - can it be set up with some content (video) and a few free apps, and then attached to an iTunes account when they connect it to their machine?  Or is it not possible to load ANY content onto the iPad without an iTunes account first?

Can I set up one iPad as the master and then 'clone' it to each individual iPad?  I assume I can do this through Backup/Restore, however they will then all be tied to the same iTunes account.  I know that I can log out of the store on the iPad and then sign in with a new iTunes account to download apps on their own accounts - however I assume iTunes will give an error when connected to a different Mac/PC and require it to be wiped?

I know lots of schools/businesses are deploying these and it seems unlikely that they're require so much manual work on the users part to get it working/syncing.

I've taken a quick look at Apple's documentation on this, but a lot of it deals with enterprise security issues, which is not my concern: http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/resources/