# Preload and preconfigure an iPad for someone else

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, software, mdm

I need to preload and preconfigure some software on an iPad, and then give the iPad to someone else.

I thought about just buying the software with my App Store account, but is there a way that I can "transfer" the ownership of the app (and the registration of the iPad itself) to the other person?

This is similar to [Is it possible to pre-install apps on an iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/is-it-possible-to-pre-install-apps-on-an-ipad) except that I *can* activate the device first, and I want to do more than just install an app, I want to be able to pre-configure everything and then (I suppose) transfer the app to the other person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do several things:

- Convince them to permit you to use their Apple ID and password (they can change the password to something you prefer - then change it back). They can also remove the credit card and let you gift the apps or redeem a gift certificate.
- Just gift them the apps and assist them as they learn.

In the long run, you'll either be acting as a custodian or want to be hands off - look at things six months from now and you can decide if you'll just be on the hook to support them perpetually or if you just want to be with them and let them do the setup so they are self sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to transfer ownership of apps already purchased. Does this person have an iTunes account already? If not, set one up and make the purchases, using a gift card, or switch the CC info when you transfer the iPad. If they already have an account, best way may be to gift the apps to the user's account (you may have to do this from iTunes on a computer).